# How to use hyperref's backref with labels other than section or page?

Tags: bibtex, cross-referencing, backref

I have a latex file with a lot of entries called "problems", each with its own \label. I would like to have bibtex show the list of problems that a given bibliographic entry refers to. I can do this with \backref, which can show the section number or page number. Is there a reasonable modification of \backref to use the problem number label that is generated?

An example follows. In the output for each bibliographic entry, a link to section 1 has been added. I'd like the first entry to link to problem 1.1, and the second to problem 1.2. I'd also like it to read that way (so instead of just the number 1.1, it says "cited in Problem 1.1).

```
\documentclass[11pt]{book}
\usepackage{amsthm} %%% DR for problems
\usepackage[backref=page]{hyperref}
\usepackage{filecontents}

\newtheorem{problem}{Problem}[chapter]

\begin{document}
\chapter{Knot theory}
\section{Introduction}
\problem[Lickorish]\label{p1.1} Conjecture: Given a knot $K$, any band connected sum with an unknot is still a knot. This follows from~\cite{K2-1}.

\problem[A) (Matumoto]\label{p1.2} Suppose the band connected sum of a trivial link (of two components) is the trivial knot. Is the band isotopic to the trivial band? See Adams~\cite{K2-2}.
\begin{filecontents}{backreftest.bib}
@article{K2-1,
  author = {Abhyankar, S. S. and Moh, T. T.},
  title = {Embeddings of the line in the plane},
  journal = {J. Reine Angew. Math.},
  volume = {276},
  year = {1975},
  pages = {148--166},
  }

@article{K2-2,
  author = {Adams, C. C.},
  title = {The noncompact hyperbolic 3-manifold of minimal volume},
  journal = {Proc. Amer. Math. Soc.},
  volume = {100},
  year = {1987},
  pages = {601--606},
}
\end{filecontents}
\bibliographystyle{plain}
\bibliography{backreftest}
\end{document}
```

Comment: there are closing braces missing in your bib. Apart from this try `\usepackage[backref=section]{hyperref}`, this will pick up the current number that you would get with \ref too.

Comment: Thanks for the correction (now incorporated into the question). I had gotten a similar suggestion to use backref=section from a friend and it seems to work.